# String doesn't want to store a 2700 character word

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make a program that prints all the numbers from 100-999. After that you get to choose how many numbers you want to find. Then you type the number's position and it will be outputed.

There is one problem. The string, named str, stops storing at the number 954.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Prints to myFile the numbers from 100 to 999 without a space in between. Like this: 100101102...999
    ofstream myFile("numere.txt");
    for(int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
        myFile << i;
    //Makes the string str to store the line: 100101102103...999. But only stores until 954 (100101102..954)
    ifstream myFileRead("numere.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(myFileRead, str))
        cout << str << endl;
    //Ouputs the lenght that should be 2700 but is instead 2565
    cout << endl;
    cout << "String legth: " << str.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    int n, k;
    cout << "Enter how many numbers do you want to find: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout << "Enter number position(it starts from 0) : ";
        cin >> k;
        cout << "Here's the number on position " << k << ": " << str.at(k);
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Try closing the output file before opening it as an input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ streams are buffered. When you use `<<` to write to a file it is not immediately written to the file.

Try to close or flush the `ofstream` before you read from it:

```
  myFile.close(); // or...
  myFile.flush();
```

For more details I refer you to [flush()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) and [close()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close).

---

PS: Actually it is rather rare that you need to close a `fstream` explicitly. You wouldn't need to do it when you used seperate functions for writing and reading:

```
 void write_to_file() {
       std::ofstream myFile("numere.txt");
       //...
 }
 void read_from_file() {
       std::istream myFile("numere.txt");
       //...
 }
```

Because the destructor of `ofstream` already closes the file.